# GET method form with ExpressJS - multiple app.get

Tags: node.js, express, url, crud

I want to make a simple login form.

This is the relevant code:

```
app.get('/login' , (req,res)=>{
    app.use(express.static('login'));
    res.render(__dirname + '/login/index.ejs');

/*This is load the login page*/
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form action="/" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password">

        <input type="submit" value="login">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the form is GET method because I don't create/update anything. If I used app.post for detecting the parameters I've used app.post and it was working fine.

But how I handle two app.get ? one for load the page, the second for handle the html form ?

For example:

```
app.get('/login' , (req,res)=>{    
    console.log(req.query);
}
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that instead of using the GET method for both the login and the displaying of your website you make your form method POST instead of GET. Then use [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) in your express app as a way to parse the received form data.

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
```

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const upload = multer();
app.use(upload.array());

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.body);
   res.send("recieved your request!");
});
```